# Load data belonging to a parent model with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Considering something similar to the example outlined [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function() {
    this.resource("post", { path: "/posts/:post_id" }, function() {
      this.resource("comments", { path: "/comments" });
    });
  });
});
```

using the `DS.RESTAdapter`. The `Router` would load all the posts when I access the `PostsRoute` with a call to the API URL `/posts`.

When I then access `PostRoute`, for example for the post with `id=1`, it doesn't hit the API again, i.e. it doesn't hit `/post/1`. It loads the post from the store.

I want then to access `CommentsRoute` for post with `id=1`. How do I load the comments?

Should I have sideloaded all the comments in the first place, when I loaded the post list? In this case though, I would need to load all the comments for all the posts. Is it possible to load the comments only when needed, i.e. when I access `CommentsRoute`?

In this case, how do I actually load the comments from the backend?
Specifically, how do I write the `CommentsRoute` to load the comments from the RESTful API when I access the page that actually displays them?

I guess one needs to have the following:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});

App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    /*
     * How do I inject params.post_id here
     * to make a request to the RESTful API?
     * Which URL would be called?
     * /comments?post_id=ID
     * /post/post_id/comments
     * ...
     */

    // Doesn't work, hits /comments
    return this.store.find('comment', { post_id: params.post_id });
  }
});
```

Why does

```
return this.store.find('comment', { post_id: params.post_id });
```

hit `/comments`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare your `CommentsRoute` like this:

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
  }
});
```

What it does is, it gets the model of the `PostRoute` and fetches its comments.

Ember-data handles the logic behind it. If comments were sideloaded, it will just return these. Otherwise it will issue a GET request to fetch them.

For this to work, you need to include the `links` property on a serialized post. The `links` property needs to include the URL you wish ember-data to use in order to fetch the comments.

E.g. your serialized post may look like this:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "links": { "comments": "/posts/1/comments" }
  }
}
```

See [DS.RESTAdapter#findHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany).

The `hasMany` relationship *probably* needs to be declared async for this to work properly:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true })
});
```

Comment: Without `async: true` it doesn't work. I assume that if you don't want to sideload the data, you need to set `async: true` and the `links` property. I tried to provide the `comments` property, with the id list and without sideloading the comments, but it didn't hit the backend when it was necessary to display the comments

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ember's sideloaded relationships to make the posts API endpoint also return the relevant comments and Ember will figure it out.

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Node is not omakase",
    "comments": [1, 2, 3]
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "body": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
  }]
}
```

You'd then be able to pass the already loaded comments to the comments route.

It may be in the docs but it's quite a specific term! Some of the concepts like that can be a bit tricky to search for.

Comment: I edited my question. Regarding your solution my question is: should I load all the comments for each post when I first load the post list, i.e. when I call `/posts`, or should I load the comments when I hit `/post/1`? I would say that my best option would be to load the comments from the backend only when I access `CommentsRoute`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following forces a call to the backend `/comments?post_id=ID`

```
App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: 'post'
});

App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('comment', { post_id: this.modelFor('post').get('id') });
  }
});
```