# Push data belonging to a parent model with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958323/load-data-belonging-to-a-parent-model-with-ember-js), the scenario is the same outlined [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/), i.e. a list of posts, each having zero or more comments.

Suppose one has the following router.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' }, function() {
      this.resource('comments', function() {
        this.route('create');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The model for a post is the following one.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true })
});
```

A post, for example, is the following one.

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "links": { "comments": "/posts/1/comments" }
  }
}
```

This way, I am able to load the comments of this post using the following route.

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
  }
});
```

The question now is: how can I create the `CommentsCreateRoute`, so that the new `comment` is actually posted to `/posts/1/comments` and not to `/comments`?

So far I have the following.

```
App.CommentsCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var newComment = this.store.createRecord('comment');
    newComment.set('title', 'test comment');
    return newComment;
  }
});

App.CommentsCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {        
    saveEditing: function(){
      var newComment = this.get('model');
      newComment.save().then(function(comment) {
        /* OK saved */
      }, function(response) {
        /* show errors */
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Does this REST scheme make sense?

```
GET /posts/{post_id}/comments
PUT /posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}
POST /posts/{post_id}/comments
```

or should I use the following?

```
GET /posts/{post_id}/comments
PUT /comments/{comment_id}
POST /comments
```

or any other? Which would be the most "standard"?

Comment: Check this out: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/

You can override the adapter for your commments so `App.CommentAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return '/posts/1/comments'; // Since this needs to be dynamic you need to implement some logic to generate this
  }
});`

Comment: I thought about it, but the function gets only the argument `type`. Where do I pull `1` from?

Comment: I am continuing to investigate this for you... But to me it doesn't actually make very much sense that you would want to do this...  Because now your are dynamically generating routes in your front end that need to be accounted for in the backend.  What is the reasoning for posting to a dynamic URL?

Comment: Each `post` has a `comments` link for `GET`, so I thought the most customary way was to use that same URL for `POST`. I updated the end of the question accordingly. Apparently I should go for the second REST scheme I posted, thanks.